# QGIS Raster Calculator tool does not have a Save to Temporary File option

Tags: qgis, raster-calculator

At 3.18.3, the **Raster Calculator** tool does not have a *Save to Temporary File* option.  Clicking the *Output layer* ellipsis only allows saving to disk.  Is there an optional way to save to a temporary file?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried GDAL's virtual file system (https://gdal.org/user/virtual_file_systems.html), specifically saving the file to `/vsimem/temp.tiff` or similar? I'm not at my QGIS machine to check if this works, but it might. (The issue being does the calculator have access to all the file capabilities of GDAL, and also whether the temp memory file will be accessible in the main QGIS process.)

Comment: Not sure if it helps  but the Raster calculator in the Processing toolbox allows saving output to temporary file.

Comment: @BenW Your comment helps immensely!  Please feel free to add it as an answer and I'll credit.  But... why limit the capabilities of the forward-facing version?  It never occurred to me (nor should it have) that a fuller version of the tool was tucked away elsewhere.  Where's the logic in this?  What similar inconsistencies are lurking out there?  Anyway, thanks for letting me cry on your shoulder.

Comment: No worries! I'm not sure why either- anyway, glad that helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not really sure why that option is not available in the Raster Calculator from the Raster menu, but if you use any of the Raster calculator tools from the Processing toolbox, you can save the output to a temporary file.

Images for the native Raster Calculator tool and its dialog are shown below, although the GDAL and SAGA raster calculator tools also allow for producing temporary output files.

[image]

[image]

Comment: @Ben_W : QGIS processing toolbox lists three different raster calculators: QGIS native, GDAL and Saga. What you mean is the first one: https://i.stack.imgur.com/e8J1j.png - great answer, however! Did not know that, thanks. Was looking for this too but thought it would not be possible.

Comment: @Babel, you're right- I was referring to the first one (native QGIS raster calculator) however, the GDAL and SAGA raster calculator tools in the processing toolbox also allow to save temporary output files!

Comment: I  have submitted this as a feature request: https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/44016

Answer (score 1):

As of QGIS 3.34, and at least as far back as QGIS 3.22.10, there is an option to create an on-the-fly raster using the Raster Calculator under the Raster menu from the main toolbar.

There is a checkbox for `Create on-the-fly raster instead of writing layer to disk`.

[image]